# subscript/superscript in Google Visualization API axes labels

Tags: google-visualization, axis-labels

How to include subscript/superscript in labels in Google Visualization API? I need some formula and subscript in google APIs.

Answer (score 3):

You can't include markup in labels, so I think your only option is to use [Unicode subscripts and superscripts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts). This should be no problem if you're just working with numbers — just replace the digits 0-9 with the corresponding characters from ⁰¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹ and ₀₁₂₃₄₅₆₇₈₉.

Most of the alphabet characters are available too, except for q. This is because the team of Unicode experts who decide on these things felt that it was more important to make room for essential glyphs like  and .